# p:accordionPanel in another p:accordionPanel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My problem is when I put `<p:accordionPanel>` in another `<p:accordionPanel>` the second `<p:ajax>` don't work, I like put

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange" 
        listener="#{functionWorkflow.onTabChangeWorkflow}"
        update="@all" />
```

for the first `<p:accordionPanel>` and

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{functionWorkflow.onTabChangeStep}" />
```

for the second `<p:accordionPanel>` like this:

```
<h:form id="formFunction">
    <p:accordionPanel value="#{functionWorkflow.listWorkflowTemplate}" var="workflowTemplate" activeIndex="null" id="panelWorkflow" dynamic="true">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{functionWorkflow.onTabChangeWorkflow}" update="@all" />
        <p:tab title="Workflow: #{workflowTemplate.nome}" >
            <h:form>
                <p:accordionPanel value="#{functionWorkflow.listWorkflowstep}" var="workflowTemplateStep" activeIndex="null"   >
                    <p:tab  title="step #{workflowTemplateStep.stepOrder} : " >
                        <p:accordionPanel value="#{functionWorkflow.logStepContatti}" var="stepContatti" activeIndex="null" dynamic="true"  onTabShow="#{functionWorkflow.onTabChangeStep(workflowTemplateStep)}">
                            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{functionWorkflow.onTabChangeWorkStep}" update="@all" />
                            <p:tab  title="Contatto: #{stepContatti.contatti.nome} : " >
                            </p:tab>
                        </p:accordionPanel>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:accordionPanel>
            </h:form>
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>
</h:form>
```

The result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t97gv.png),
[image]

Finally I would like calling different methods for only level `<p:accordionPanel>`.

Help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to put accordion into accordion before, so there may be a bug, but firstly I would recommend to remove one of the `h:form`s. You should never put form into form. If this doesn't help, i will run a quick test on this.

Comment: thanks you for your reply, i know that , but i have try it with form and without form, all time error, if you have idea for i use another mode say me that i try it, thank you (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: What is you `#{functionWorkflow.onTabChangeStep(workflowTemplateStep)}` code doing exactly?

Comment: Which PrimeFaces and JSF version are you using? I can't reproduce the issue with MyFaces 2.2.2 and PrimeFaces 4.0.12

Comment: The methode #{functionWorkflow.onTabChangeStep(workflowTemplateStep)} initial call database with hibernate for initial another List for i can see it in the next <p:accordionPanel> if u like we can delete it and we use ajax, i have put it just for try, but and if idelete it the second <p:ajax> is not called, i use primefaces 3.5 and MyFaces 2.2

Comment: Can you please try it with PrimeFaces 4.0?